# From $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have some questions that are all related.

They all revolve around getting a better understanding of phrases like "the column space of $A$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^m$, not $\Bbb R^n$).

Similarly, a linear transformation is said to take something from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$. What exactly does that mean to take something from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^m$?

Does $\Bbb R^n$ represent the number of column vectors?

Does $\Bbb R^m$ represent the number of components/elements of those vectors? (I.e.. So if I had two column vectors that would be $\Bbb R^n$ but if those two columns had $5$ components/elements that be $\Bbb R^m$?)

If it does represent these things, I'm still not sure what it means that something "lives in" $\Bbb R^m$ as opposed to $\Bbb R^n$.

Thanks for any help

Comment: It's the number of dimensions in the space. Generally, $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a $k$-dimensional space, where each element is a real number. So, if a vector is an element of $\mathbb{R}^k$, it has $k$ components, one for each dimension. A vector with 3 real components is an element of $\mathbb{R}^3$, a coordinate pair of the form $(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are both real is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$, etc.

Comment: A linear transformation doesn't "live" in either space, as you frame it, but maps elements from one space to the other. Let's say you have a matrix $T$ that maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then, given a vector $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (so $x$ has $n$ components), the vector that results from the operation $Tx$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^m$ (it has $m$ components).

Comment: The vector x would be based on the number of columns/variables , correct? And the vector that results from the Matrix/Vector product is an element of Rm because???

Comment: The vector $x$ would be an $n \times 1$ matrix, just a single column with $n$ elements. If $T$ maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, then $T$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. And then, when you multiply $Tx$, you have an $m \times n$ matrix times an $n \times 1$ vector, resulting in an $m \times 1$ vector (column with $m$ elements), and that's an element of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental concept you need to understand is that of a function/mapping. Roughly speaking, a function consists of a triple of information $(f,X,Y)$. Here, $X$ and $Y$ are sets, and $f$ is a "rule" which assigns to each element of $X$ a uniquely determined element of $Y$. We write this as $f:X\to Y$. The set $X$ is called the **domain** of $f$, the set $Y$ is called the **target space/codomain** of $f$; also given an element $x\in X$, we denote by $f(x)\in Y$ the uniquely determined element of the set $Y$ which corresponds to $x$ via the rule $f$.

Now, I've mentioned that $X$ is the domain and $Y$ is the target space. There is another important subset to keep in mind, namely the **image** $f[X]:=\{f(x)\,|\, x\in X\}$. This is the set of all possible outputs. Note that $f[X]$ is always contained  in $Y$, meaning $f[X]\subset Y$, but it need not be equal (think of $Y$ as a dart board, and $f$ as a machine which shoots darts (i.e elements of $X$). Then all the places on the dart board which actually get hit by a dart is called the image).

In the context of linear algebra and matrices, what is going on is that if you're given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with real entries, then we can define a function $f_A:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^m$. How? Essentially by matrix multiplication:
\begin{align}
f_A(x):= A\cdot x
\end{align}
where we think of $x$ as a column vector ( $A$ is $m\times n$ and $x$ is $n\times 1$ so the result $A\cdot x$ is $m\times 1$ so everything makes sense). Note that all we're doing is giving a certain rule for how elements of one set, $\Bbb{R}^n$, get mapped to the elements of another set, $\Bbb{R}^m$.

When talking about the column space of the matrix $A$, this is nothing but the image of the function $f_A$ in the sense I have defined above, i.e
\begin{align}
\text{column space}(A)&\equiv f_A[\Bbb{R}^n]=\{f_A(x)\,|\, x\in \Bbb{R}^n\}=\{A\cdot x\,|\, x\in \Bbb{R}^n\}\subset\Bbb{R}^m
\end{align}
In words, it is the set of all possible outputs of the function $f_A$. As you can see from the definition itself, the column space of $A$/ the image of the function $f_A$ is a **subset of the target space** $\Bbb{R}^m$.

Note that you shouldn't place so much emphasis on the letters $m,n$. What is important is to keep track of the domain and target space. For example, if $A$ is a $4\times 7$ matrix (i.e $4$ horizontal rows and $7$ vertical columns) then we get an associated function $f_A:\Bbb{R}^7\to\Bbb{R}^4$. So, the column space of the matrix will be a certain subset of $\Bbb{R}^4$.

Perhaps one slightly confusing situation is when $m=n$. For example, suppose $A$ is an $8\times 8$ matrix. Then, the function is $f_A:\Bbb{R}^8\to\Bbb{R}^8$. In this case, the image is a subset of $\Bbb{R}^8$, which is both the domain and target space. But in this situation, conceptually we should think of two different copies of $\Bbb{R}^8$, one which represents the domain and another which represents the target space.